# Export-Csv end with blank sheet

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I wrote script to get directory, filename, and count of lines, but when I exported to CSV I end with null sheet. What am doing wrong?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\bi\Desktop\MOMO_FILES -Include *.txt -Recurse 
$result = % {
  $_ | select CreationTime, DirectoryName, name, @{n="lines";e={
    Get-Content $_ | Measure-Object -Line | select -expa lines
  }}
 }
 $result | Export-Csv C:\Users\bi\Desktop\filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not incorporating the `Get-ChildItem` part in to your pipeline. You need to do this:

```
$result = get-childitem C:\Users\bi\Desktop\MOMO_FILES -Include *.txt -recurse  | % { $_ | select CreationTime, DirectoryName,name, @{n="lines";e={
   get-content $_ | 
     measure-object -line |
         select -expa lines }
   } 
} 
$result | Export-csv C:\Users\bi\Desktop\filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or if you want it to be a little less horizontal, send the `Get-ChildItem` result to a variable and use that:

```
$files = get-childitem C:\Users\bi\Desktop\MOMO_FILES -Include *.txt -recurse 
$result = $files | % { $_ | select CreationTime, DirectoryName,name, @{n="lines";e={
   get-content $_ | 
     measure-object -line |
         select -expa lines }
   } 
} 
$result | Export-csv C:\Users\bi\Desktop\filename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```